# as3 dynamic reposition & scale of textField, can it be done?

Tags: actionscript-3, dynamic, position, scale, textfield

Is it possible to set a textField on stage dynamically and allow for stageHeight & width changes with resize event.

Stage say (500 x 250), doesn't really matter as example and any text, (xml, inline, whatever). I took this example from republicofCode as an example as I've spent all day trying different theories and have convinced myself that it's not humanely possible, despite in appearance being the simplest thing ever. Please HELP resolve the mystery at least. . .

```
stage.scaleMode = StageScaleMode.NO_SCALE;
stage.align = StageAlign.TOP_LEFT;

var myText:TextField = new TextField();
myText.text = "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog";
myText.addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, onAddToStage);

addChild(myText);

myText.wordWrap = true;
myText.width = 150;
myText.height = 40;
myText.x = 100;
myText.y = 100;

function onAddToStage(event:Event):void {
    stage.addEventListener(Event.RESIZE, adjustTextField);
    trace("text definitely onStage");
}  

function adjustTextField(event:Event):void {
    trace ("adjustTextField being fired!");
    myText.x = stage.stageWidth / 2; // ANYTHING THAT WORKS
    // myText.y = stage.stageWidth / 2; //ANYTHING THAT WORKS
    trace ("adjustTextField fired and still nothing happening. . . !");

    trace ("height" +stage.stageHeight);
    trace ("width" +stage.stageWidth);
}
```

What gives?

If you copy & paste the code you should get a textField that positions itself at x.100 & y.100, in theory, by scaling the flash player it should then move the top left corner of the textField to the center of the scene. But NO. ?! WTD!

I'm not after rescaling the text, just altering it's position and the width of the textBox to accomodate a larger or smaller text area subject to the stage either being enlarged.

I've googled for a day and not seen a single example of this working so maybe it just can't be done but surely something so trivial is possible, after everything else you can do in flash, surely this is beyond complication!

- AMENDED - Post crash solution in place, will restore previous attempts on project version and upload the code once I've gotten the scrollbar in place and the ratio alignment fixed.

Comment: Did you trace stage.stageWidth?

Comment: Hi, an embarrassed pause. . . Flash just crashed and on relaunch the test code above worked straight away. Just testing my original again!

I'll cry if it's a temp bug that's been stuttering my day away, I've been going insane wondering why I couldn't get it to work!!!

Razors on standby. . .

Comment: ouch! but good to know it's working. (And I guess your scaleMode was already set correctly?)

Comment: Well, that tops off a rather sh*te day nicely! Thanks simon, an inspired trace event helped push my Flash over the edge and on relaunch the test scene above works.

My main scene is still causing me distress however I suspect it's now something to do with adding a scrollbar after the initial xml is loading and not comensating for the new resize actually working.

One of those days where you rewrite things so many times you lose what's what.

Time to have a break me thinks and then take stock of what might have worked earlier this morning.!?*&%!

Razzle Frazzle. . .

Answer (score 0):

You should read about [scaleMode](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/Stage.html#scaleMode).

I added

```
stage.scaleMode = StageScaleMode.NO_SCALE; 
stage.align = StageAlign.TOP_LEFT;
```

to your example code to make it work.

(I also had to move the ADDED_TO_STAGE listener up, to add it before the addChild call, but if you are already seeing your traces you don't need to change that)

Comment: Thanks, the code above I yanked from online as I was getting to the point of self doubt after today, I'm originally pulling my text from an xml file, adding scrollbars etc and blending it so I figured it may be somewhere in that which was causing my problem.

I've been pulling my hair out with scale all week anyway which is why I was so p*ssed today when working on something so trivial, all the nightmare stuff worked first time, this, bah!

I should have just designed several different size websites! Quicker and easier I think!